# \bookmark does modify the defaut view to fit PDF

Tags: bookmarks, zooming

I am having some issues using the `\Bookmark` to try to add separate pages for navigation in PDF. The issue, comes, when clicking the `Cover`, where the `\Bookmark` is used, it automatically **switches zoom to** `fit`, this is annoying, instead of preserving the current zoom and scrolling to the top of the page.

**Output:**
[image]

**My problem:**
[image]

**My latex:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}

% Do not change
\textheight = 220mm
\textwidth = 150mm
\topmargin = 10mm
\oddsidemargin = 5.0mm
\evensidemargin = 5.0mm
\unitlength = 1mm

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\phantomsection
%\hypertarget{cover}{}
\bookmark[dest=\thepage,level=0]{Cover}


\ifodd\value{page}\else\mbox{}\newpage\fi
\thispagestyle{empty}
{
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
}

\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\section{Section 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1.2}

\cleardoublepage
\section{Section 1.2}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2.2}

\cleardoublepage
\section{Section 2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1.2}

\cleardoublepage
\section{Section 2.2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.2}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** *This latex posted here is an MVP, so you can easily test this. I been checking the bookmarks documentation with absolutely no result.*

**EDIT** *If, `\pdfbookmark` can be used, how can it be configured to begin from the beginning of that page, and not somewhere in the middle.*

**EDIT** *Using, `\bookmark[page=\thepage,view={XYZ null 0 null},level=0]{Cover}` results into this:*

[image]

**EDIT:** `\bookmark[view={XYZ null 0 null}, startatroot, numbered=1, page=1,level=0]{Cover}`, **jumps to the second page, not the first...**

Comment: Please include information on which viewer you are using in the body of the question. I don't see an issue with TeXShop or Preview on a Mac. But Acrobat does exhibit the problem you mention.

Comment: @PeterGrill, the Firefox browser. *But this shouldn't matter*.

Comment: Please add that to the body of the question as it is relevant information.

Comment: @PeterGrill, it doesn't matter, same result in Adobe Acrobat Reader, even the latest version.

Comment: Yes, thats what I said "Acrobat _does_ exhibit the problem". And the viewer _does_ matter as Preview and TeXShop don't show that problem.

Comment: The described behavior is the specified behavior for this type of link, so if TeXShop and Preview behave differently than that's a bug. (Or at least they don't support this aspect of the PDF spec)

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: I think both TeXShop and Preview use Apple's pdfKit, so if anyones knows how to report this bug to Apple, they should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to fit the page, you can use another `view` parameter. To keep the current zoom level, you want `XYZ`. Additionaly you want to specify a `page`, not a `dest` since you don't have a named destination (This only looked like it worked since pdfTeX redirects all links to non existing destinations to the first page.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}

% Do not change
\textheight = 220mm
\textwidth = 150mm
\topmargin = 10mm
\oddsidemargin = 5.0mm
\evensidemargin = 5.0mm
\unitlength = 1mm

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\phantomsection
% Now add the bookmark. We want to keep the zoom level, keep the horizontal position but go to the top of the page, so we use `XYZ null \calc{\paperheight}`
% \bookmark[dest=\thepage,level=0]{Cover}
\bookmark[page=\thepage,view={XYZ null \calc{\paperheight} null},level=0]{Cover}


\ifodd\value{page}\else\mbox{}\newpage\fi
\thispagestyle{empty}
{
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
}

\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\section{Section 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1.2}

\cleardoublepage
\section{Section 1.2}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2.2}

\cleardoublepage
\section{Section 2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1.2}

\cleardoublepage
\section{Section 2.2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.2}

\end{document}
```